# Handle animations within an MVC pattern using Pygame

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pygame

I am currently trying to implement an MVC pattern using Python and Pygame, but I can't figure out how to properly handle animations. Let's say we have a model object that can attack:

```
class ModelObject:
    def attack():
        if not self.attacking:
            self.attacking = True
            # Then compute some stuff

    def isattacking():
        return self.attacking
```

And a view object that renders the model object by displaying an attack animation:

```
class ViewObject(pygame.Sprite):

    attacking_ressource = [] # List of surfaces for animation
    default_ressource = None

    def update():
        # Detect the model object is attacking
        if self.model.isattacking():
            # Create animation if needed
            if self.attacking_animation is None:
                self.attacking_animation = iter(self.attacking_ressource)
            # Set image
            self.image = next(self.attacking_animation, self.default_ressource)
        else:
            # Reset animation
            self.attacking_animation = None
            self.image = self.default_ressource
```

The question is, how do the model know that it's no longer attacking?
The view could notify the model when the animation is over, but it guess it's not how the MVC pattern is supposed to work. Or, an animation counter could be set in the model, but it doesn't seem right either.

Comment: Do you *need* to tell the model when the animation is finished? If you "fire and forget" an `attack` command to the view, the view just ignores further commands from that model until the attack is complete.

Comment: I thought about it, but what if the model object is not supposed to do anything else while attacking, like attacking twice during the animation?

Comment: That's a good point. I think this question might be better suited to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it the wrong way round.

The attack should not last as long as the animation, but the animation should last as long as the attack.

So the `ViewObject` is fine as it already asks the model if it is still attacking.

---

As for the `ModelObject`, it's up to you how long the attack should last and how to keep track of time. You could for example call `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get the number of millisconds since you started your game once in `attack`, and then periodically check it again, like:

```
class ModelObject:
    def attack():
        if not self.attacking:
            self.attacking = True
            self.started = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            # Then compute some stuff

    def isattacking():
        return self.attacking

    def update():
        # attack lasts 1000ms
        self.attacking &= pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.started < 1000
```

Comment: Hum, that makes sense! So I guess I should define a number of ticks for attack in the model so the view can use this value to adapt the animation (duplicate or pass some images) in order to match the model attack duration, is that right?